# how can I change the form of alphabet in this string?

Tags: javascript

I want to make string 'hello' to 'hElLo' which is only even number in the index changes to capital letters.

Source code:

```
function toWeirdCase(s){
 var str = s.split(''); // var str = {'h','e','l','l','o'}
 for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str.length[i]%2===0){
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
   }
  }

console.log(toWeirdCase('hello'))
```

But the result is `undefined`

Comment: The `if` condition never gets executed. `str.length[i] % 2 === 0` doesn’t make sense. What is `str.length[i]` supposed to mean?

Comment: `return s.split('').map((c, i) => i % 2 ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowercase()).join('');`

Comment: the problem with your code is `str.length[i]%2===0` is never true ... so, your function doesn't return anything, therefore it's the same as `return undefined` - however, that "condition" isn't the only problem. Because, if you fix that, then the function will return `str.toUpperCase()` the first time that condition is true, so, you'd only process part of the input string, and then `str` is an array, and it has no `toUpperCase` method, so you'd end up with an error in the console. basically everything from `if` to the closing `}` is wrong

Comment: thank you now I am getting understand of what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```js
function toWeirdCase(s) {
  var str = s.split(''); // var str = {'h','e','l','l','o'}
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {                      //Test the index and not the letter
                                            //Since the goal is to capitalized the odd numbers (array starts at 0). You can use the condition i % 2 !== 0. This means the index reminder is not 0.
      str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase();        //Assign the value
    }
  }

  return str.join('');                      //Join the array and return
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('hello'))
```

Comment: judging from original code, you want to test `i%2===0` - edit: nevermind, just saw expected output :p

Comment: Yeah.. But that will result to `HeLlo` and not `hElLo`. Ill add this on the comment :)

Comment: no, all good, your code is fine - - original code was so wrong it made no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` with a regex to convert  to uppercase each letter having an odd index:

```js
function toWeirdCase(s) {
  return s.replace(/./g, (m, i) => i % 2 ? m.toUpperCase() : m);
}
console.log(toWeirdCase('hello'));
```